# strong_params: Handling Dynamic Number of Nested Objects/Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

#### The Problem

I have a model Foo that can accept nested attributes for a model Bar.  Using rails conventions for nested models in forms, `form_for` and `fields_for` create a `params` hash of the form:

```
{...
  :foo => {
    :name => "Lunes",
    :bar_attributes => {
      1 => {
         label: "gato"
         },
      2 => {
         label: "perro"
         }
    }
  }
}
```

But, strong_params wants me to explicitly whitelist each attribute.

```
def foo_params
  params.require(:foo).permit(:name, bar_attributes: {1: [:label], 2: [:label]}
end
```

#### The question:

The number of hashes in `:bar_attributes` is dynamic.  Do I need to dynamically generate my `foo_params` method, specifically the `:bar_attributes` hash?  Or is there a way to whitelist the params that I want generally, and not for each individual sub-hash of `:bar_attributes`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `params.require(:foo).permit(:name, bar_attributes: [:label]}` should work fine, but only if the `bar_attributes` keys are strings (i.e. '1' and '2' instead of 1 and 2).